# Json::decode returns NULL

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-8, guzzle

I have problem with `Json::decode`. I'm using this code:

```
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;

$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
$request = $client->post($rest_url, [
        'form_params' => [
          'id' => $rest_id,
        ],
      ]);
      $response = Json::decode($request->getBody());
```

to get JSON from some server but it returns NULL. Of course this is just a part of the code (without `try`, `catch`...)

`$request->getBody()` return is ok, but in `Json::decode` I'm still getting NULL.

The only thing I noticed is that in Postman, when I look at raw body content, I see some empty lines at the beginning of the JSON (like return on keyboard when typing), but I checked JSON as it is on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it's valid.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Looks like `Json::decode` doesn’t do anything more than calling PHP’s native `json_dcode` ... so use `json_last_error`/`json_last_error_msg` to find out what went wrong.

Comment: yes, it's syntax error...so I'll request fixed JSON from client (because it's generated through some theirs internal software)...thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Drupal's JSON serializer, but try to force response body conversation to a string.

```
$response = Json::decode($request->getBody()->getContents());
```

Guzzle return a Stream object from `getBody()`, it could be the issue.